# Get key Char on Key Press Event

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, keyboard, keyboard-events

How to get a key char even the Window form not in focus?

I have a Window Form, Here I wrote a Key press Event.

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
        MsgBox(e.KeyChar.ToString)

    End Sub
```

It will works only when the form has focus.

But I want to know to get the key char even the form not in focus.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This event is supposed to capture the key being currently pressed on the form (= when it is focused). The events are associated to controls (objects) and, consequently, only triggered when the corresponding action is executed on the corresponding control. For example: if you add a textbox to your form, it would also have a KeyPress event which would be triggered by the action pressing-key + focused-textbox. To know the key being currently pressed by the user independently upon anything else, you would have to rely on keyboard hooks (you should do some pre-research before asking).

Comment: @varocarbas Thank you So much for your Reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must register global keyboard hook in winapi : actually there is good c# wrapper with source code on codeproject : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook

Comment: Thanks for your Reply Dude. Its Useful one.